# How do you open multiple images into a single Photoshop file?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

I need to open 30 images in a single file as multiple layers. I went to `File > open > select 30 images > open` and it was opening 30 files in different windows. I had to use the Drag And Drop method for 30 files to make all the images appear in one file with multiple layers.  So my question is there any way to open multiple images in in single Photoshop file as Layers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`File > Script > Load Files into Stack...`

Comment: For "Load Files into Stack" script, there are two use options for selecting files as entire folders or just files. Moreover we can automate applying "Auto-Align Layers" option using the same script. In the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8TqX1WBkYrk, its showing how the script will act with different options